# I want to save an entire blob (.bin) file from the database into an array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with a data (.bin/ blob file) stored into it. I'm using the following code to output the data from the .bin file:

```
function connect_db() {
    $server = '****';
    $user = '****';
    $pw = '****';
    $db = '****';
    $connect = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pw,$db);
    if(!$connect) {
        die('Connection error: '.mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    return $connect;
}

function get_blob() {
    $connect = connect_db();
    $query = 'SELECT blob FROM my_table';
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         header('Content-type: text/plain');
         $blob[]=$data;
    }
    return $blob;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(get_blob());
echo '</pre>';
```

This gives me the following output (this is one of the many values in the array that I get back from the database):

```
[24] => Array
    (
        [data] => a:1:{s:7:"context";a:5:{s:11:"product_ids";s:6:"entity";s:19:"add_to_cart_combine";i:1;s:30:"show_single_product_attributes";i:1;s:12:"display_path";s:8:"node/171";s:6:"entity";a:3:{s:11:"entity_type";s:4:"node";s:9:"entity_id";s:3:"171";s:28:"product_reference_field_name";s:14:"field_products";}}}
```

I was looking for an image, but it seems this blob doesn't contain one. However I still would like to save all this data correctly into an array (multidimensional probably). I was planning to use explode, but that seems a little far fetched. Is there a way for me to get clean data without using explode too much?

Comment: From the looks of it, the content of the blob seems to be an array already, have you tried saving it as such?

Comment: This much more seems like serialzed thingy. Tried `unserialize()`?

Comment: I tried unserialize. That just gives me a huge empty array back (3000+ keys). I'll see if I can save it as an array as is, but eventually each different value in the blob needs to be a different item, since I have to parse it into an xml file.

Comment: I guess I did something wrong while using unserialize, since an online unserializer works perfect. I'll look into it some more, thanks for the answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38829952/267540

Comment: @e4c5 I already fixed it with unserialize(), but thanks for the link anyway. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

The data is JSON encoded

Replace

```
$blob[]= $data;
```

with

```
$blob[]= json_decode($data);
```

Or maybe (it's not exactly clear from your post)

```
$blob[]= json_decode($data['data']);
```

or

```
$blob[]= json_decode($data['blob']);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: I used unserialize, and I get a clean print_r back now. The problem now is that this .bin file does not contain an image, so I have to look through thousands of bin files to hopefully find the correct path to the server. Thanks for the answer anyway!